# Where is the "Set Product as New" attribute saved in the Magento 2.3 EE database?

Tags: magento2.3

I know that Magento 2 EE doesn't utilize the `"newsFromDate"` and `"newsToDate"` attributes, but I can't figure out where Magento EE is storing the data for the `"Set Product as New"` option on the products?

I'm trying to check if a product is new, but I'm unsure what to use to get that data if I can't find it in the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**"Set Product as New"**  field does not store value on the database level.
`module-catalog-staging` is the module which is having implementation and in the backend,
Magento EE also uses `setNewsFromDate()` and `setNewsToDate()` which depends on module-staging version id (`vendor/module-catalog-staging/Model/Product/Hydrator.php`)

For rendering check below file from the same module - `Ui/DataProvider/Catalog/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php`

For processing
-> Look at the `UpdateProductDateAttributes.php` observer under `vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/Observer/UpdateProductDateAttributes.php`